# no me funciona document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = variable;

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

[image: No funciona innerHTML]
A pesar de ser un codigo muy simple no puedo lograr que salga en pantalla el valor de la variable. Tambien intente pasandole directamente un string pero no me funciona

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido(a) a SOes. El código no debería mostrarse a través de imágenes, puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/557263/edit) tu pregunta y poner el código con su respectivo formato. Mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Quita los parentesis despues de innerHTML. Diría que sobran.

Comment: innerHTML no es un método, es una propiedad, por la cual no debería ir los paréntesis. El error es solo eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @masterguru los comentarios no son para responder a la pregunta, solo son para sugerir modificaciones a la preguntas o pedir mas información

Comment: @Csharis, gracias por tu comentario.  Las preguntas que solo tienen errores tipográficos son cerradas con el tiempo, y lo habitual es no darles respuesta formal. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación para votar para cerrar preguntas verás que es uno de los motivos de cierre estipulados más comunes . Y si te fijas en el título de la pregunta (donde lo escribe bien) y luego en su código (que no deberia ser imagen) verás que aún más corrobora que es un error tipográfico, por lo tanto lo arreglamos en los comentarios y con el tiempo la pregunta desaparecerá de aquí gracias a las revisiones.

Comment: @Csharls una respuesta de una línea aporta poco o ningún valor, por lo que este tipo de preguntas suele ser ignorada

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que innerHTML no es una función, es una propiedad a la que le tienes que asignar el valor, así que con quitarle los paréntesis debería funcionarte:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="output"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const hello = 'Hola Mundo'
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = hello
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El tag esta bien puesto pero la constante no...
Si vas a meter solo texto en la constante, te recomiendo usar las comillas dobles.

```
const saludo = "Hola";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = saludo;
```

Comment: Yo diría que las comillas dobles no hacen ninguna diferencia, y que no guardan relación con el problema de la pregunta. Cuál es el razonamiento que te llevó a esa respuesta?

Comment: Utilizar el paréntesis en innerHTML() si que hay diferencia y las camillas dobles insertan solo texto, las comillas simples insertan código

Comment: Además te dejaste al final de cada declaración el punto y coma.

Comment: Los punto y coma son opcionales en Javascript.